# Finding volume via integration

Tags: calculus

When we are asked to find the volume for example of a sphere,we slice it into numerous disks with small depth $dr$ and get the infinitesimal volume $dV$.And then we sum those slices together by putting an integral symbol.But my question is the basic integration we learnt was to find area under the curve.In that case we proved that the area is simply the anti derivative of the function.But here how do we use integration by putting an integral symbol before $Adr$ without proving that the derivative of the volume is the area of the disks?I am so disturbed by this as I didn't see any author giving the proof with proper intuition.

Comment: You might be looking for Cavalieri's principle, which is an instance of Fubini's theorem.

Comment: "area is simply the derivative of the function"... No, area is the anti-derivative (slope is the derivative).

Comment: The area under the curve is the integral, not the derivative. Also, "putting an integral symbol before" something just means that you are adding continuously; as opposed to $\sum$ that is discrete.

Comment: Yeah i fixed the typing mistake,thanks

Comment: But i still don't understand why we can apply the derivative of the area logic in this case

Comment: In these texts, I strongly suspect that the authors are not trying to say that the derivative of the volume is the area of the discs. An integral is a continuous analogue to a discrete sum. $A$ is the area of the discs, with a thickness of $dr$, and so each disc has a volume $Adr$. If you have a finite number of these, you can them up to get a total volume $\sum Adr_i$. As $dr\rightarrow 0$, the sum becomes an integral, $\int Adr$.

Answer (score 1):

What the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus actually tells us is that *in general*,
$$\int_a^b g(x)~dx=\lim_{\delta x\to0}\sum_{x=a}^{x=b}g(x)\delta x$$
Applying this to your example gives us the required formula.

---

This is how we can apply it volume. Suppose we have a function $f(x)$, and we want to revolve around the $x$ axis the area bounded by $x=a$, $x=b$, the $x$ axis and $y=f(x)$ to form a volume, $V$.

Consider a very small strip of the volume that is created, at a point $x$. This will be a cylinder with width $\delta x$ and its radius of its $2$ flat surfaces will be $f(x)$. So the volume of this cylinder is $$\pi r^2h= \pi [f(x)]^2\delta x$$

Hence, using the fact that for *any* function $g(x)$ we have
$$\int_a^b g(x)~dx=\lim_{\delta x\to0}\sum_{x=a}^{x=b}g(x)\delta x$$ we see that the total volume, $V$, that we are interested in is equal to
$$\lim_{\delta x\to0}\sum_{x=a}^{x=b}\pi[f(x)]^2\delta x=\pi\lim_{\delta x\to0}\sum_{x=a}^{x=b}[f(x)]^2\delta x$$
which is equal to
$$\pi\int_a^b[f(x)]^2~dx$$
as required. We can apply this very easily to a sphere by considering a circle's Cartesian equation: $x^2+y^2=r^2$

Comment: But this is just a mathematical expression of Riemann sum which is area under the curve,how can we apply that to volume?

Comment: @AritraBarua  It's *not* necessarily the area under the curve. It works for any function $f(x)$. Should I elaborate in my answer about how to apply it to volume?

Comment: Yes,please,i will be greatly helped

Comment: @AritraBarua btw what is a Riemann sum?

Comment: @AritraBarua is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sphere, centred at the origin, with a radius of $R$. Now think of slicing the sphere into discs of thickness $dr$. The disc has a surface area of $\pi r_i^2$, where $r_i$ is the radius of a single disc, so has volume $\pi r_i^2 dr$.

What is $r_i$? It is found by realising that $r_i$ is the horizontal side of a right-angled triangle with $R$ being the hypotenuse and $r$ being the vertical side. Draw it out to convince yourself.

To find the volume of the sphere, we have to add up all of the $\pi r_i^2dr$. This is an integral over $r$, which ranges from $-R$ to $R$:
$$
V = \int_{-R}^R \pi (R^2 - r^2)dr.
$$
Can you take it from here?